# Why does RStudio not display the source of a function during debugging even if I have used `keep_source = TRUE` in `devtools::install`?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio, devtools

I want to debug the function `diffCalc` of the R package [diveRsity](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diveRsity/index.html). To archieve this, I cloned the corresponding git repo

```
git clone https://github.com/kkeenan02/diveRsity.git
```

Then, in R, I attempted to install the package using `devtools`:

```
# Sys.setenv(MAKE = 'make -j8') # If you want to speed up compilation
devtools::install(pkg = 'diveRsity/', keep_source = TRUE)
```

However, when I want to debug `diveRsity::diffCalc`:

```
library(diveRsity)
debug(diffCalc)

data(Test_data, package = 'diveRsity')
Test_data[is.na(Test_data)] <- ""
test_result <- diffCalc(infile = Test_data, outfile = "myresults",
                        fst = TRUE, pairwise = TRUE, bs_locus = TRUE,
                        bs_pairwise = TRUE, boots = 1000, para = TRUE)
```

RStudio gives me a warning called

> Debug location is approximate because the source is not available.

Also, the function object of `diffCalc` does not have any `srcref` attribute attached:

```
attributes(diffCalc)
## NULL
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the source with comments displayed in RStudio during debugging when the function is inside a package?